# Substantivierung von Verben

Tags: nominalization

Meine Frage ist nach welchen Pronomen man Verben bei einer Substantivierung großschreibt.
Denn ein Signalwort für die Substantivierung von Verben ist, wenn Pronomen davor stehen, aber kann mir da jemand sagen wann genau, weil es heisst ja „Wir lernen etwas Spannendes“ und nicht „Wir Lernen etwas Spannendes” oder?
(Ich hoffe man kann verstehen was ich damit meine:-))

Comment: Es scheint so zu sein, dass du nicht nach der Substantivierung von Verben, sondern von Partizipien fragst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diese Frage hat nicht viel mit Verben zu tun, denn *spannend* ist zwar ein Partizip I und damit von einem Verb abgeleitet, aber von der Wortart her ist es Adjektiv und verhält sich wie alle anderen Adjektive.

Es gilt: Substantivisch gebrauchte Adjektive und Partizipien werden großgeschrieben. Dies gilt vor allem dann, wenn sie mit Wörtern wie "allerlei", "alles", "etwas" usw. in Verbindung stehen. Dies folgt aus §57 der amtlichen Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung.

Comment: Das ist richtig und für den Eingeweihten hinreichend genau. Aber es gibt da eine Reihe von Komplikationen und Missverständlichkeiten, die ich einmal zu benennen versucht habe. Die Fragestellung fand ich so  naiv - vielleicht ist sie auch eulenspiegelhaft -, dass mir eine zusätzliche genauere Erklärung nützlich erschien.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage ist für mich nicht eindeutig verständlich, weil weder der Begriff *Pronomen* noch der Begriff *Verb* hier gut passt. Ein substantiviertes Verb hätten wir in dem Beispiel:

> *Das Gehen* fällt dem alten Mann immer schwerer.

Wie man sieht, folgt hier alles der normalen Großschreibungsregel, nach der Substantive groß geschrieben werden. *Das Gehen* ist Subjekt, welches aus dem Artikel *das* und dem Substantiv *Gehen* besteht. Daran stört nur, dass man *gehen* normalerweise als Verb kennt. In vielen Fällen ist der Infinitiv so etwas wie die natürliche Substantivform eines Verbs:

> Sein liebstes Hobby ist *Wandern* / *das Wandern*.

Der Übergang vom Verb zum Substantiv ist manchmal unmerklich:

> Er möchte am Wochenende wieder wandern.
>
> Er mag nicht mit uns wandern.
>
> Er mag nicht wandern.
>
> Er mag Wandern nicht.
>
> Er liebt Wandern.
>
> Er mag das Wandern in freier Natur.

Andere Verbformen, die häufig "substantiviert" werden, sind die Partizipien. Die Partizipien sind quasi natürliche Adjektivformen eines Verbs; sie heißen im Deutschen auch *Mittelwort*, weil sie zugleich Verb- und Adjektiveigenschaften haben. Hier Beispiele als Adjektive:

> Partizip 1: der *springende* Punkt, bei *laufendem* Motor, eine zu Herzen *gehende* Geschichte
>
> Partizip 2: die frisch *geputzten* Fenster, das *weggeworfene* Altpapier, bei *geöffnetem* Fenster

So wie man die bekannten Adjektive fast beliebig als Substantive verwenden kann:

> *das Alte* muss *dem Neuen* weichen | das *Interessante* an dieser Sache ist ...

so kann man auch diese Partizip-Adjektive "substantivieren":

> Partizip 1: Ich habe heute *Dringendes* zu erledigen.
>
> Partizip 2: das in der Vorlesung *Gehörte* so gut es geht mitschreiben; alles fertig *Verpackte* zur Post bringen

Im Beispiel *etwas Spannendes* haben wir den Fall, dass eine Bedeutung zweimal die Wortart (genauer: seine Wortartfunktion) wechselt. Ausgangswortart ist das *Verb spannen*. In der hier gemeinten Bedeutung kommt es, soweit ich sehe, nur noch in der Redewendung *jemanden auf die Folter **spannen*** vor (*= to keep sb.on tenterhook*), figurativ für *jemanden sehr neugierig machen*. Daraus wird zunächst ein Adjektiv (*eine **spannende** Geschichte*), welches sich dann **mit** (*er hatte **viel** Spannendes zu erzählen*) oder **ohne Begleiter** (*er hatte *Spannendes* zu erzählen*) in ein Substantiv verwandeln kann.

*Spannend* wird heute fast ausschließlich als Adjektiv verwendet und daher rein als Adjektiv empfunden; dass es sich aus einem Verb ableitet, ist heute im alltäglichen Sprechen niemandem mehr bewusst und es wäre falsch, es hier als Verb zu sehen oder zu bezeichnen. Es funktioniert als Gegenwort zu dem Nur-Adjektiv *langweilig*.

Solche 'Neu-Substantive' haben - wie andere Substantive auch - manchmal einen Artikel oder so etwas Ähnliches wie einen Artikel (z.B. *alles* in *alles fertig Verpackte*). Und dieses *so etwas wie einen Artikel* schafft Probleme.

Ärgerlicherweise machen nämlich manche Grammatiken immer noch keinen Unterschied zwischen sogenannten 'Pronomen' in der Funktion eines echten Pronomens im Wortsinn (ein Wort, das *für* = *pro* ein *Nomen* eine syntaktische Stelle im Satz besetzt. z.B. Subjekt, Objekt) einerseits, und andererseits einem "Pronomen" in der Funktion eines Begleiters / Artikels / Artikelworts / Determinanten ... Fast alle Formen der "Pronomen" können auch in Artikelfunktion auftreten, so auch z.B. die Indefinita. Und selbstverständlich ist ein solcher Begleiter als Teil einer Nominalphrase nicht zugleich der Stellvertreter dieser Nominalphrase. **Der Begriff *Pronomen* ist hier** ein logisches Unding und **in höchstem Maße irreführend.**

Ein solcher Fall ist das Indefinitum *etwas*. Es tritt auf als Pronomen:

1. Willst du *etwas* von mir? [*Akkusativobjekt*]
2. *Etwas* stimmt hier nicht. [*Subjekt*]
3. Sie sprach *von etwas*, von dem ich noch nie gehört hatte. [*präpositionales (von-) Objekt*]

aber auch als Begleiter / Determinant / Artikelwort:

4. Willst du noch *etwas Brot* haben?
5. Dienstag würde mit dem Termin für mich passen, da habe ich nachmittags noch *etwas Luft* (= Zeit).

Die Bedeutung in 4 und 5 ist wie die von *ein bisschen*: eine unbestimmte, aber kleinere Menge von einer Sache, die man normalerweise ohne Artikel benennen würde.

Wenn in einer Grammatik steht, dass 'substantivierte Wörter' hinter einem als Begleiter verwendeten "Pronomen" (gemeint ist: Begleiter) groß geschrieben werden müssen, dann ist das eine unbeholfene Ausdrucksweise für "Teilweise lässt sich an einem vorangehenden Artikelwort erkennen, ob ein nachfolgendes Wort als Substantiv zu verstehen ist und daher groß geschrieben werden muss." Aber aufpassen!: Zwischen das Artikelwort und das (neugeschaffene) Substantiv können noch klein geschriebene Adjektive treten! Man schreibt also:

- *Ein* einfaches *Nein* würde mir besser gefallen als *diese* ewigen *Vielleichts*.
- In dem Büro ist *ein* ständiges *Kommen* und *Gehen*.
- Ich habe heute *unseren Neuen* bei seinen Kollegen vorgestellt.
- Weiß man schon *irgendetwas* *Neues* über die Lage in Italien?
- *Viele Unterrichtende* bei den freien Bildungseinrichtungen sind zurzeit arbeitslos.
- *Die* heute neu *Angekommenen* bitte ich, mir zu folgen.
- Bei dieser Sache kann *nichts Gutes* herauskommen.

Leider wird diese Regel nicht konsequent angewendet:

- *das ist etwas **a**nderes* vs. *das ist etwas **G**leiches*.

Außerdem ist es in ziemlich vielen Fällen nicht möglich, zu entscheiden, ob es sich bei einem Substantivbegleiter um ein Adjektiv oder um ein Indefinitum in Artikelfunktion handelt, z.B. in den folgenden Beispielen:

- In folgende**m** ganz neu aufgetretene**m** Fall entschieden die Richter anders > *folgendem + aufgetretenem* = Adjektive mit paralleler Flexion
- In folgende**m** ganz neu aufgetretene**n** Fall entschieden die Richter anders > *folgendem* = Artikelwort, *aufgetretenen* = Adjektiv mit schwacher Flexion
- In de**m** folgende**n** ganz neu aufgetretene**n** Fall > *dem* = Artikel, *folgenden + aufgetretenen* = Adjektive, schwach flektiert.

---

Zu der Frage, welche "Pronomen" auch als Artikelwörter auftreten können, ist die Antwort: praktisch alle Indefinita und alle weiteren, die in einer gegebenen Nominalphrase an die Stelle eines vorhandenen bestimmten oder unbestimmten Artikels treten könnten. Zu letzteren gehören die Demonstrativa (diese/r/s...; jene/r/s), Possessiva (mein/e, dein/e, sein/e, ihr/e...), der Negativartikel *kein/e* und natürlich alle, die man sowieso schon als Artikel kennt, die Zahlwörter, die Frageartikel *welche/r/s* und *was für ein/e*, auch alle (unveränderlichen) Indefinita mit *-erlei* (*vielerlei, mancherlei, solcherlei, welcherlei, dieserlei, derlei, zweierlei, dreierlei ...*).

**Nicht** dazu gehören natürlich **die Personalpronomen** (ich, du, er ...) in den verschiedenen Kasus (mich, dich ... / mir, dir ... / meiner, deiner ...), die so gut wie nie innerhalb von Nominalphrasen auftreten, sondern praktisch immer alleinstehend den Platz und die Funktion einer Nominalphrase in einem Satz vollständig ausfüllen. Dazu lassen sich allerdings Ausnahmen finden: *Ihr Neuen geht bitte zuerst ins Lager und lasst euch Arbeitskleidung geben*, oder dieses schein-mitleidige *Du Armer!* In diesen Ausnahmefällen behalten die Pronomen ihre Satzgliedfunktion und werden nicht zu Artikelwörtern, die Konstruktionsweise nennt sich *Apposition*. Für die Reflexivpronomen (mich, dich, sich ... / mir, dir, sich ...) gilt das Gleiche.

Eine vollständige Liste der in Frage kommenden Pronomen wäre recht lang. Ein paar weitere Beispiele mögen genügen:

*die **beiden Kleinen**, offen für **alles Neue**, **einiges Missverständliche** wurde korrigiert, **viel Interessantes** gesehen haben, **manches Fremde** erscheint einem am Anfang irgendwie falsch, es gibt hier **nichts Neues / wenig Neues** zu erzählen,  **so etwas Unverschämtes** habe ich noch nie erlebt, **alle Neuen** mal herhören!,  **irgendein Verrückter** hat über die Nacht den Strom abgestellt, **einige Oberschlaue** hier wissen angeblich, wie man sich in die Bundestagcomputer reinhackt; **ein paar Unerschrockene** stellten sich den Angreifern entgegen; gab es **irgendwas Besonderes**?; heute sollen wir **jemand Neuen** als 'Mädchen für alles' bekommen; **jeder Zehnte** bekommt ein kleines Geschenk; **alles Kaputte** endlich wegwerfen ...*